# iPhone app sending data while closed

Tags: objective-c

I want to send data to my web server while the app is closed. Is that possible? I've read I can send the position, but I waant to send some id of the phone too.

If it's not possible to have the app running, could I at least communicate with it from my server and then do stuff in the background?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the app goes into the background the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method on your App Delegate will get called.

In that method you can use the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` on `UIApplication` object to start background processing.

Just realise that you don't get forever to perform tasks in the background. You can find out how long you have left by reading the `backgroundTimeRemaining` property in `UIApplication` if you need to know if you're running out of time.

If your processing is short you should be fine, but remember if your processing requires network access then you can't be sure how long that will take.

Comment: It's been my observed experience that in current (at least upto iOS 5) you get 10 minutes of background processing time. However, that may be depended on different factors (perhaps battery life, etc) and your experience may differ.

Comment: And what about from the server ask for info to the app, similar procedure as the notifications, but I dont actually send info, I just awake the app to send me new data.

Comment: You can not communicate (or wake up) an app that is not running from a remote server on iOS. Something similar can be achieved using Apples Remote Notifications service (as that service is an iOS level service that is always running).